# Store images into array and display them into angular view

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filereader

I am making a gallery of images where user can upload images and display it into the view, the problem that I pushed the images into an array but I couldn't display them into the view.

this is the view in angular component 
gallery.componet.html

```
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                      <img for="profileImage" src="assets/common/add_image.svg" class="upload-placeholder" />
                      <input #gallery type="file" accept="image/*" name="profile image" (change)="imageUpload($event)"/>
                      <label for="profileImage" class="mt-3 font-weight-bold">Add Photo Gallery</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="gallery" *ngFor="let item of gallery">
                    <img src="{{item}}" width="300px" height="300px">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

function to get the image and push it to the gallery array

gallery.component.ts

```
gallery = [];
  imageUpload(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        this.gallery.push(e.target.result);
      };
    } 
  }
```

**stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4usrg

**Error message**

Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object HTMLInputElement]' of type 'profile image'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is also tagged gallery. Try to change it.

```
<input #galleryFileInput type="file" accept="image/*" name="profile image" (change)="imageUpload($event)"/>
```

Comment: Lool thanks man, I am sorry for the stupid fault @MoxxiManagarm